# how to Disable Dark mode in in my application

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11, ios-darkmode

I just want override dark mode UI in my application. I added `UIUserInterfaceStyle` is `Light`. But i am not sure it is not working. Is there any other option?

Comment: try this call in appdelegate `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            // disable dark mode
           window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
               }`

Comment: just add userinterfacestyle in your plist and put Light

Comment: not working. @Anbu.Karthik,

Comment: @antonioyaphiar not working.

Comment: @Suyash - please update your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For entire App (Window):

```
window!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

You can get the window from `SceneDelegate` or any `view.window`

- For a single ViewController:

```
viewController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

You can set any `viewController`, even inside the viewController it**self**

- For a single View:

```
view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

You can set any `view`, even inside the view it**self**

You may need to use `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { ,,, }` if you are supporting earlier iOS versions.

Answer (score 3):

**For Objective C entire App:**

```
_window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
```

Comment: Thank you, its working i add in the app delegate

Answer (score 2):

You can force light or dark mode in your whole application regardless of the user's settings by adding the key **UIUserInterfaceStyle** to your **Info.plist** file and setting its value to either **Light** or **Dark**.